# react-native-fbsdk fb login not working on iOS 11.3.1 (Firebase)

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

Before iOS 11.3 my app is working fine, but after the ios 11.3 was released new users from facebook cannot login to my app. But exisiting users still can login via facebook using their fb accounts. 
im new too React native can please anyone help me. this is my facebook login code:

```
export const fbLogin = () => async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: LOADING_TRUE });
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions([
        'public_profile',
        'user_birthday',
        'email',
        'user_photos'
    ]).then(
        result => {
            if (result.isCancelled) {
                console.log('cancelled');
                dispatch({ type: ERROR_HANDLER });
            } else {
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(data => {
                    const token = data.accessToken;
                    fetch(
                        'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id,name,email,gender,birthday&access_token=' +
                            token
                    )
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(json => {
                            let userData = json;
                            let id = userData.id;
                            const fbProfilePic = `https://graph.facebook.com/${id}/picture?height=150`;
                            dispatch({
                                type: GET_PROFILE_PICTURE,
                                payload: fbProfilePic
                            });

                            const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
                                token
                            );
                            firebase
                                .auth()
                                .signInWithCredential(credential)
                                .then(user => {
                                    console.log('firebase facebook login!');
                                    let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                                    if (currentUser !== null) {
                                        const name = currentUser.displayName;
                                        const email = currentUser.email;
                                        const uid = currentUser.uid;
                                        const birthday = json.birthday;
                                        const gender =
                                            json.gender === Languages.common.male_en
                                                ? Languages.common.male
                                                : Languages.common.female;
                                        userData.gender = gender;
                                        let userDetails;
                                        const db = firebase.firestore();
                                        const docRef = db.collection('users').doc(uid);
                                        docRef
                                            .get()
                                            .then(doc => {
                                                if (doc.exists) {
                                                    // more than 2 times login
                                                    dispatch({
                                                        type: GET_USER_DATA,
                                                        payload: doc.data()
                                                    });
                                                } else {
                                                    // first log in
                                                    const dateCreated = Moment()
                                                        .format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
                                                        .toString();
                                                    userDetails = docRef.set({
                                                        name,
                                                        email,
                                                        birthday,
                                                        gender,
                                                        dateCreated,
                                                        uri: fbProfilePic
                                                    });
                                                    dispatch({
                                                        type: GET_USER_DATA,
                                                        payload: userData
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            })
                                            .catch(error => {
                                                dispatch({
                                                    type: ERROR_HANDLER,
                                                    payload: error
                                                });
                                            });

                                        Actions.checkInHistory();
                                    }
                                })
                                .catch(error => {
                                    dispatch({
                                        type: ERROR_HANDLER,
                                        payload: `Error: ${error}`
                                    });
                                });
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            dispatch({
                                type: ERROR_HANDLER,
                                payload: err
                            });
                        });
                });
            }
        },
        error => {
            dispatch({
                type: ERROR_HANDLER,
                payload: error
            });
        }
    );
};
```

Then this error is appearing: [image]

this error is coming from my last error handler

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what happened but when I put `LoginManager.logOut()` before the `LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions()` new facebook users can now login to my app.